# Is there any way to transfer ownership of a CloudKit shared record?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

*I've just spent hours evaluating CloudKit's sharing features for a potential multi-tenancy app and, while I think I know the answer, I felt I should ask the community.*

**The use case**: an app that supports multiple companies, each with its own users that can access shared data (records) within that company only. Imagine Slack's separate workspaces: a user of Company A should be able to see all of Company A's data, and maybe eventually Company A hires a new employee (user), who also should see that same data. Company B has completely separate users/data and is never seen by anyone from Company A.

**The question**: from my understanding so far of CloudKit, records are associated to a user, not a company/team/group. If User A (of Company A) shares a record with User B, that's totally doable and User B will see everything (including child records). But now let's suppose User A leaves the company. How does another user then take ownership of those records so that User B can continue to access the company's data?

It almost seems like each company would need to have its own iCloud account to serve as a master "owner", which feels unprofessional or challenging for non-techies to understand (and thereafter complicated for sharing with future users).

Am I thinking about this wrong? Am I already barking up the wrong tree by considering CloudKit as the backend for this app?

Answer (score 0):

I think the most suitable setup for what you've described is to use a `Public` database in a CloudKit container. A `CKRecord` can be shared and "owned" however you want. The record remains available to all who can access the database.

Sharing a `CKRecord` via the `CKShare` functionality is much more limited. When sharing that way, you are simply providing a shared view into someone's `Private` database. If that user vanishes, the shared record goes with them and the sharing stops. Only the `Public` database can preserve a record independent of user status.

One caveat is that a `Public` database has to be owned by a single Apple Developer account. You can't share ownership across companies at the business level. But for the purposes of your app, your dev account can own the database and you can share the data with as many tenants as you want.

Let me know if you have any follow-up questions.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding you correctly: I would setup a `Public` database, ultimately owned by the developer account associated with my app, and all data would get stored as records within that database. Presumably I would then have a field within each table/record that could identify the tenant/company it's intended for, and it'd be up to my app's filtering logic to ensure users only see what they're meant to see, correct? I shouldn't worry at all security-wise about this being a `Public`  CloudKit database?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You don't need to worry about the `Public` database. Apple chose a weird name for what it really is. It's "public" in the sense that anyone using your app can access the data in it, but it's not open to the whole world to read and write to. Only your app can access the data.

Comment: u have to worry about security. while other apps can't see the data in the public database, another company/user can. ie Company A can see Company B's data within your app. You can use your app logic to limit that but you are vulnerable to a malicious actor bypassing that because the public database itself has nothing that will stop that.